# Startup sequence for the LPC1343

Tags: arm, lpc

I'm exploring my first ARM device, the LPC1343. I'm using VIM and ARM GCC.

I have managed to light an LED but to blink it I will need to startup the clock and PLL. Right now I can't find the right sequence for this in the user manual.

Where can I find the basic startup sequence for clock and PLL for the LPC1343?

So far I came up with the following not working sequence:

```
void InitSys (void) {
    InitCpu();
    InitPorts();
}
void InitCpu (void) {
    PDRUNCFG |= 0x00000020;      // SYSOSC_PD = 1 -> System oscillator Powered Down
    SYSOSCCTRL = 0x00000000;     // Oscillator is not bypassed, 1 - 20 MHz frequency range
    PDRUNCFG &= ~0x00000020;     // SYSOSC_PD = 0 -> System oscillator is Powered
    InitPLL();
    SYSAHBCLKDIV |= 0x00000001;   // System Clock Divide by 1
    MAINCLKUEN &= ~0x00000001;    // No change
    MAINCLKSEL = 0x00000003;      // Main clock source select register -> System PLL clock out
    MAINCLKUEN |= 0x00000001;     // Update clock source
}
void InitPLL (void) {
    PDRUNCFG |= 0x00000080;         // Set SYSPLL_PD
    SYSPLLCLKUEN &= ~0x00000001;  // No change
    SYSPLLCLKSEL = 0x00000001;      // System oscillator
    SYSPLLCLKUEN |= 0x00000001;     // Update clock source
    SYSPLLCTRL = 0x00000025;        // FCLKOUT = 72 MHz /// M div = 6 / P div = 2
    PDRUNCFG &= ~0x00000080;        // Set SYSPLL_PD
    while(!(SYSPLLSTAT & 0x000000001)){}  //If 1 -> PLL locked
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the manufacturer provide the CMSIS framework?  You'll have an easier time if you use it.

Comment: The manufacturer is pretty vague about it, and has loads of examples always attatched to something more, i have a hard time learning if you throw to much stuff at me at the same time.
Im just looking for a basic step by step, turno on the register, load this register with xxxxx, and so on and so on.

Comment: It took me enought just to get the linkerscript and vector table to work, i dont want to use another one now.

Comment: My limited experience w/ ARM Cortex is that the CMSIS framework is the way to go.  "load this register, load that register, load the next register,..." WILL drive you crazy.

Comment: I believe i found it in NXP website under the name, NXP LPC Cortex-M3 IEC60335 Class B library, i still believe its vague or at least not very obvious, there is to many scatered information and no obvious answer, like maybe, default template libraries from scratch, or something, forgive me if im too basic.

Comment: Apologies, NXP doesn't buy in to the CMSIS, or has at least been a bit different.  Their "equivalent" is LPCOpen.  See http://www.lpcware.com/content/forum/lpcware-cmsis-driver-development-now-dead-it-seems-all-development-work-lpcopen -- personally, I'm critical of the decision.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything to start the clock, and it's not necessary to start the PLL in order to blink an LED. By default the processor wakes up running at 12 MHz, using the internal RC clock directly. As long as that's a fast enough clock for your purposes you don't need to do anything else.

The manufacturer (NXP) is not at all vague about starting the clock and PLL. There is C code to do this in the `system_LPC13xx.c` file that comes with their examples (at least with the LPCxpresso examples). The clock is configured in the `SystemInit()` function.

Update: If you are using the `lpcopen` package, look for `clock_13xx.c`

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <lpc13xx.h>

void delay(void);

int main(void)
{
    LPC_GPIO0->DIR = (1<<7); //Config PIO0_7 as Output
    
    while(1)
    {
        LPC_GPIO0->DATA = (1<<7); //Drive output HIGH to turn LED ON
        // Better way would be LPC_GPIO0->DATA |= (1<<7);
        
        delay();
        LPC_GPIO0->DATA = 0x0; //Drive output LOW to turn LED OFF
        // Better way would be LPC_GPIO0->DATA &= ~(1<<7);
        
        delay();
    }
    return 0; //normally this wont execute
}   

void delay(void) //Hard-coded delay function
{
    int count,i=0;
    for(count=0; count < 4500000; count++) //You can edit this as per your needs
    {
        i++; //something needs to be here else compiler will remove the for loop!
    }
}
```

Ex. 7)

Comment: Please use the code formating feature and explain how this answes the question of the OP (especially 8 years after the question was beeing asked)